# Can't get Vue.js transition work without a warning message

Tags: vue.js

I am using [Vue.js transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements) to fade elements in/out based on conditional rendering.

First, I am transitioning a group of components. This is working perfectly!

```
<div>
    <transition-group name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
        <component-one key="1" v-show="foo === 'one'" :type="type"/>
        <component-one key="2" v-show="foo === 'two'" :type="type"/>
        <component-one key="3" v-show="foo === 'three'" :type="type"/>
    </transition-group>
</div>
```

Each component `<component-one.../>` is identical. I am rendering a bunch of `<div>` elements:

```
// component-one.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="div-one">
            <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                <div key="one" v-if="foo === 'bar'">
                    <h3>My First Div</h3>
                    ...
                </div>

                <div key="two" v-if="foo === 'bazz'">
                    <h3>My Second Div</h3>
                    ...
                </div>

                <div key="three" v-if="foo === 'other'">
                    <h3>My Third Div</h3>
                    ...
                </div>
                ...
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The *functionally* works great. The components fade in/out nicely as to the div elements. However, I am getting a warning from vue:

> [Vue warn]:  can only be used on a single element. Use  for lists.

This makes sense as I am transitioning a group of div elements. However, if I use `<transition-group>` the mode of `out-in` is no longer working. As I toggle through my div elements, they snap in/out of position as they are fading in/out. I have tried every combination -- including using `v-if` or `v-show` to see if that made a difference.

How can I use the transitions I have (that work) but not generate the warning?

Comment: can you wrap the div in a parent div or v-container?

Comment: Hm your example is quite literally straight from the docs here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes , so i guess it should work. Maybe your `v-if` statements actually overlap and try to show 2 divs at the same time?

Comment: I tried the parent `div` approach, no luck. It could be the if/show are conflicting. I'm trying to figure out how to get this in a codesandbox or something to help everyone see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

`Adding "keys" on each item.

try this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    foo: "bar"
  },
  methods: {
  
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="foo = 'bar'">show bar</button>
    <button @click="foo = 'bazz'">show bazz</button>
    <button @click="foo = 'other'">show other</button>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <div key="one" v-if="foo === 'bar'">
        <h3>bar</h3>
      </div>

      <div key="two" v-if="foo === 'bazz'">
        <h3>bazz</h3>
      </div>

      <div key="three" v-if="foo === 'other'">
        <h3>other</h3>
      </div>
    </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Evan - I've got keys on each of the `div` elements. I'm still seeing the warning. It's odd, everything is working *great*, vue is just not happy at all.

Comment: Hello sir. are conditions/variables on each div generated after the dom is rendered? did you have "created()", "mounted()" etc... that affects the "v-if" ? (sorry English not my first lang)

Comment: Nope. The markup that is above is the final output on screen. The html is actually hard-coded div elements; they aren't even rendered in a `v-for`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the transition element is supposed to wrap just one element and that the reason `v-show` isn't working is because `v-show` doesn't actually add/remove anything from the DOM, it just toggles the visibility attribute. If you use any logic that could theoretically show more than one at the same time, you'll get a warning. So what I think you'd really want is for your transition element to wrap each of the individual `component-one` elements. `v-show` should take care of the individual element's visibility. Basically, you need the final markup to look like this:

```html
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <div key="one" v-if="foo === 'bar'">
    <h3>My First Div</h3>
    ...`enter code here`
  </div>
</transition>
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <div key="two" v-if="foo === 'bar'">
    <h3>My Second Div</h3>
    ...
  </div>
</transition>
```

Try doing either:

1. A `v-for` on the `transition` component that loops through a list of all the items you'd like to render. Each transition should have its own `component-one` child as it loops through the list.

```html
<transition v-for="(item, index) in items" name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <component-one :key="index" v-show="foo === item" :type="type"/>
</transition>
```

2. Wrapping the *contents* of `component-one` inside a `transition`. That would include the transition inside the `component-one` element. Then you can render `component-one` elements without any transition elements as a parent.

*component-one*

```html
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <div>
    <!-- Component One contents... -->
  </div>
</transition>
```

*main*

```html
<div>
  <component-one key="1" v-show="foo === 'one'" :type="type"/>
  <component-one key="2" v-show="foo === 'two'" :type="type"/>
  <component-one key="3" v-show="foo === 'three'" :type="type"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are in fact correct and should be considered by anyone who comes across this thread. I also wanted to add what I found was the underlying issue.

I was using `<transition-group>` on my parent element(s) that I was trying to transition between. Each component that I was transitioning *to* had multiple div's underneath. This is what was bubbling up (for lack of better words) that was looking for a `<transition-group>`.

**TL;DR:**
The error was coming from the child component(s) that needed to make use of `<transition-group>`.

Seems obvious now, but hope can save other folks some time.